# PL/SQL - Calculate distinct days between overlapping time periods

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Imagine this scenario (YYYY/MM/DD):

```
Start date: 2015/01/01 End date: 2015/08/10 
Start date: 2014/10/03 End date: 2015/07/06 
Start date: 2015/09/30 End date: 2016/04/28
```

Using PL/SQL can I calculate the distinct days between these overlapping dates?

**Edit:** My table has 2 DATE columns, Start_Date and End_Date. The result I'm expecting is 515 days ((2015/08/10 - 2014/10/03) + (2016/04/28 -2015/09/30))

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  In your example, do you have a table with two columns and three rows?  If so, are the columns of type `date` or `varchar2`?  Or do you have a table with three rows and a single column that you need to parse?  Or do you have something else?  What is the result that you want given that sample data?

Comment: So is your goal to count the number of days that appear in any interval in the table?  Your calculation is very different from any of the possibilities I considered from the text of your question.

Comment: @JustinCave By "calculate the distinct days between these overlapping dates" i mean that if there are overlapping dates count those "overlapped days" only once. Those 3 records are the dates that two employees worked on a project. I want to count the total number of days the employees spent working on the project. If two employees are working on the project on the same day, only count that day once.

Comment: OK.  So your goal is to count the number of days that appear in any interval in the table?  I believe that's what you're saying.  But you didn't just say "yes" to my question so I'm not sure if you're asking something else...

Comment: so you want to know how many days between the widest range of dates from left column to the right column, i.e. 2014/10/03  -> 2016/04/28 ? Good luck.

Comment: Stewart Ashton has several posts on methods to merge overlapping date ranges (e.g. https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/merging-overlapping-date-ranges/). These may be useful as a starting point from which the elapsed days can be calculated.

Answer (score 5):

You can do also with pure SQL (no need for PL/SQL):

```
    with 
    minmax as (select min(start_date) min_dt, max(end_date) max_dt from myTable ), 
    dates as (
SELECT min_dt + rownum-1 dt1
FROM minmax CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= (max_dt - min_dt +1)
)
select count(*) from dates
where exists( 
 select 1 from MyTable T2 
 where dates.dt1 between T2.start_date and T2.end_date )
```

NOTE: an idea, written from head, not tested. Adapt generated dates as needed, with start date and needed length.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Using actual table dates

Comment: What happens if there is a date in 2017 (i.e. more than 1000 days from 2014-01-01) or before 2014?

Comment: @MTO Improved to use actual dates

Comment: `min_dt + rownum` will return you one day too little, since you start preparing dates from min_date + 1 (also, condition in CONNECT BY clause should be corrected).
Also, in the `EXISTS` clause it would be good to join some users_table (if the table with project dates has foreign key from users_table - e.g. user_id).

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1e12/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DATES ( start_date, end_date ) AS
          SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', DATE '2015-08-10' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2014-10-03', DATE '2015-07-06' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2015-09-30', DATE '2016-04-28' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT COLUMN_VALUE ) AS number_of_days
FROM   DATES d,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT d.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY d.START_DATE + LEVEL - 1 < d.END_DATE
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
         )
       )
ORDER BY 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1e12/10/0)**:

```
| NUMBER_OF_DAYS |
|----------------|
|            522 |
```

**Query 2 - Check**:

```
SELECT DATE '2015-08-10' - DATE '2014-10-03'
     + DATE '2016-04-28' - DATE '2015-09-30'
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1e12/10/1)**:

```
| DATE'2015-08-10'-DATE'2014-10-03'+DATE'2016-04-28'-DATE'2015-09-30' |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                 522 |
```